# how to retrieve the firebase data of whole month entry for every day and also find the highest value for each day?

Tags: ios, iphone, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

`here I am trying to get the highest pain level of each day of a month and save it in an array and plot it as a chart.I managed to get the pain level, but it retrieves only entered date alone .. I need to check date 1 to 31 of a month ...if its a nonentried day means..it should return 0 to the array.....any help will be appreciated..?

my code`

```
   func DataFromFirebase()
   {
     var u_id = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser!.uid
     print(u_id)

      databaseRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("medical_details")
      databaseRef.queryOrderedByChild("user_id").queryEqualToValue(u_id).observeEventType(.Value, withBlock: { (snapshot) in
        for the item in snapshot.children
           {

            let c_date = item.value!!["created_date"] as! String


            let Key = item.key
            //reference to the selected key
            let usersRef = self.databaseRef.childByAppendingPath(Key!!)
            //reference to the medicine node inside the key
            let Ref = usersRef.childByAppendingPath("parts_list")

            Ref.observeEventType(.Value , withBlock: { (snapshot) in
                for the item in snapshot.children
                {
                    let date = item.value!!["date"] as! String

                    if (c_date == date)
                    {
                    let dosage = item.value!!["pain_level"] as! String
                     print(dosage)
                    }
                }
            })

           }
    })
}
```

here my Firebase DB Structure

```
"-KfBHEzFkEpfy0g2sU4S" : {
  "created_date" : "14/2/2017",
  "created_time" : "15:36",
  "medicine" : {
    "-KfBHEzYDrMII9o2OECQ" : {
      "dosage" : "2mg",
      "frequency" : "8",
      "interval" : "10",
      "number_of_tablets" : "2",
      "reminder" : "",
      "tablet" : "Dilaudid"
    }
  },
  "parts_list" : {
    "-KfBHEzbFQEBEjFk5uLN" : {
      "comments" : "cgsg",
      "date" : "14/2/2017",
      "pain_level" : "3",
      "part_name" : "Leg",
      "time" : "15:36"
    },
    "-KfBHEzeY45XKs-u8S9H" : {
      "comments" : "vhdh",
      "date" : "14/2/2017",
      "pain_level" : "8",
      "part_name" : "Mouth",
      "time" : "15:36"
    }
  },
  "remedies" : "Heating Pad",
  "user_id" : "xqgiYomblxcFbSnO0Q9T5fFOKWL2"
},
```

need to retrieve that pain level according to all days of a month..?

Comment: You've included a link to a picture of the JSON tree in your question. Please replace that with the actual JSON as text, which you can easily get by clicking the Export JSON link in [your Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data/). Having the JSON as text makes it searchable, allows us to easily use it to test with your actual data and use it in our answer and in general is just a Good Thing to do.

Comment: Please post your structure as text. Also, you're going to have some issues with the structure as it is as there are dates within the user name and the dates within the parts list node. It's probably too deep as well and the question doesn't specify which dates to go by and what the child nodes are in the parts_list node. You probably need to [Denormalize](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2013/04/denormalizing-your-data-is-normal.html) aka flatten, your structure to be able to get to the data you want.

Comment: as asked...posted the DB structure..so need to get that pain_level..inside parts_list...based on date...condition to check all days of a month..eg..if march 1 means..no data entered in that date means vil give 0 to the array...like wise upto 31 days...for every month.